# OCaml variable type generalization

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, polymorphism, ocaml

I am trying to compile the following code using ocamlc.

```
type 'a splitter = {name: string; decision_function : 'a  -> bool}

let splitter12a = {name="x1>x2"; decision_function=(fun x -> x.(1)>x.(2))};;

let generate_splitter i j  = {name="x"^string_of_int(i)^">x"^string_of_int(j); decision_function=(fun x -> x.(i) > x.(j))} ;; 

let splitter12 = generate_splitter 1 2;;
```

However, the compiler complains :

```
File "error.ml", line 7, characters 17-38:
Error: The type of this expression, '_a array splitter,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized
```

I don't understand why I can declare a specialized `splitter12a` whereas `generate_splitter` cannot generate specialized splitters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into the so-called *value restriction*. For an explanation, see e.g. the section of the same title in [this chapter](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html) of Real World Ocaml.

Edit: The usual work around (probably suggested in that chapter) is *eta expansion*, meaning to expand out one lambda, e.g., by turning a definition `let f = g a` into `let f x = g a x`. But that doesn't apply to your case, because the RHS of your def does not result in a function. There is indeed no direct workaround for what you want to do.

One way is turning it into a functor:

```
module MakeSplitter (X : sig val i : int val j : int end) =
struct
  let splitter = {name = "x"^string_of_int(i)^">x"^string_of_int(j); decision_function = fun x -> x.(i) > x.(j)}
end

module Splitter12 = MakeSplitter(struct val i = 1 val j = 2 end)
let splitter12 = Splitter12.splitter
```

Another way would be using an auxiliary record type with a polymorphic field, very similar to the struct above.

Comment: Thank you ! What is the most decent workaround ? I am not familiar with "eta expansion" and specializing the splitter (the workaround I am using now) is not a viable solution

Comment: There is indeed no direct workaround, but see my edit.